# PHP Contact Form Returning empty fiels to my email

Tags: php, html

I created a PHP contact form on my website. The form is sending emails but all fields are appearing empty in the email. my code is below, any suggestions to solve this issue?

```
 <?php
    if ($_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        $car_marke = $_POST ['Marke'];
        $car_modell = $_POST ['Modell'];
        $car_vorname = $_POST ['Vorname'];
        $car_name = $_POST ['Name'];
        $car_adresse = $_POST ['Adresse'];
        $car_plz = $_POST ['PLZ/Ort'];
        $car_telefon = $_POST ['Telefon'];
        $car_email = $_POST ['Email'];
        $car_bemerkungen = $_POST ['Bemerkungen'];

        $from = 'test@gmail.com';
        $to = 'test@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Formular';

        $body = "Marke: $car_marke\n Modell: $car_modell\n 
                        Vorname: $car_vorname\n Name: $car_name\n Adresse: $car_adresse\n 
                        PLZ/Ort: $car_plz\n    E-Mail: $car_email\n Telefon: $car_telefon\n Bemerkungen: $car_bemerkungen\n";
    }
 ?>

 <?php
        if ($_POST ['submit']) {
            if (mail ( $to, $subject, $body, $from )) {
                header ( "Location: http://www.exampledomain/send.php" );
            } else {
                echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>';
            }
        }
   ?>
```

Comment: What do you get if you do a var_dump() on the $_POST array?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix sorry i did not understand what you mean

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Could you please show an example

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan thank you but i dont know how to incorporate this function in my code. I need a more concrete example to my code. I am not very well versed in PHP

Comment: Just type this `var_dump($_POST);` under `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` this line and attach the result.

Comment: How do you submit the data to this php file?

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan this method did not work

Comment: @richardsocker I am submitting the data via an HTML file this is the form code. <form action="send.php" name="form" id="form" method="post">

Comment: What do you mean var_dump "did not work"? It prints out the values in $_POST to the screen. Do you mean it displayed an empty array? Nothing at all? Or do you mean it didn't solve your problem? It's not going to fix your problem... it will help debug it. **If you're learning to code, knowing how to debug is the single most important skill you need to learn.**

Comment: @FluffyKitten I am receiving an email via the contact form and I only getting the field label, the info entered in the contact form are not showing for example I get the title Marke: and nothing entered next to it

Comment: Thats nothing to do with var_dump. Did var_dump work as I asked?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same if to all script:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$car_marke = $_POST['Marke'];
$car_modell = $_POST['Modell'];
$car_vorname = $_POST['Vorname'];
$car_name = $_POST['Name'];
$car_adresse = $_POST['Adresse'];
$car_plz = $_POST['PLZ/Ort'];
$car_telefon = $_POST['Telefon'];
$car_email = $_POST['Email'];
$car_bemerkungen = $_POST['Bemerkungen'];

$from = 'test@gmail.com';  
$to = 'test@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Formular';

   $body = "Marke: $car_marke\n Modell: $car_modell\n 
Vorname: $car_vorname\n Name: $car_name\n Adresse: $car_adresse\n 
PLZ/Ort: $car_plz\n    E-Mail: $car_email\n Telefon: $car_telefon\n Bemerkungen: $car_bemerkungen\n";



   if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    mail ($from, $subject, $body, $to) 
    header("Location: http://www.exampledomain/send.php");
    } else { 
      echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>'; 
      }
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: this is my HTML code for the form
            <form action="send.php" name="form" id="form" method="post">

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working' you get an empty mail or you don't get a mail at all?

Comment: I am getting an email with title of the category (for example: Marke:) but info entered in the input field is not showing

Comment: what is more confusing is I have a another contact form in the website with same structure (HTML and PHP) and it is working.

Comment: Do you have a name attribute to all your form elements? pls post your html code.

Comment: apparently there was some bug in the file itself once I saved as I was able to make the input field return info. Thank you for all your help

Comment: I have another issue now. I need to be able to reply to the sender email directly when I receive email from the contact form. Any ideas about how to do that in my PHP code please.

Comment: after send the mail send another mail again with the same subject and switch the $from with $to. I edited my answer.